# array indexoutofbound in android in quiz app

Tags: android

```
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4;
Button chk,next;
TextView que;
public static int Marks,Correct,wrong;
int flag = 0;
public static String[] question={"11*11","2+5","19/1"};
public static String[] ans={"121","7","19"};
String[] opt={"22","131","121","1111","25","7","52","70","19","1","not Possible","0"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
    que=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    chk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    rb4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb4);
    rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);


next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RadioButton uans =  (RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String uansText = uans.getText().toString();

            if(uansText.equals(ans[flag]))
            {

                Correct++;
            }
            else
            {
                wrong++;
            }
            int len = que.length()-1;
            flag++;
        if(flag<=len)
        {
            que.setText(question[flag]);
            rb1.setText(opt[(flag*4)]);
            rb2.setText(opt[(flag*4)+1]);
            rb3.setText(opt[(flag*4)+2]);
            rb4.setText(opt[(flag*4)+3]);

        }
        else {

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Result.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }



        }
    });
```

I am developing a quiz app, when we press next button it will check for the correct answer and then display new questions and options and after completing all questions it will display result in new Result Activity.

It throws an error line array indexoutofbound when we reach the last question instead of switching to Result Activity.

help me to solve this error
thank you in advance

Comment: Post your logcat...you will get array index of bound exception when you are trying to get access to values that is not there in the array...for eg: if the length of array is 3, but trying to access 4th...at this point you will get the exception...

Comment: `array indexoutofbound` means you are trying to read some thing which is not in your array

Comment: select log use ctrl+C to copy...

Comment: 03-23 03:38:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

Comment: one line is not enough, we understood that you got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, post complete log here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

    RadioGroup rg;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4;
    Button chk, next;
    TextView que;
    public int Correct, wrong;
    int flag = 0;
    public static String[] question = {"11*11", "2+5", "19/1"};
    public static String[] ans = {"121", "7", "19"};
    String[] opt = {"22", "131", "121", "1111", "25", "7", "52", "70", "19", "1", "not Possible", "0"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        que = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que);
        chk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chk);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb3);
        rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb4);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);

        que.setText(question[flag]);
        rb1.setText(opt[(flag * 4)]);
        rb2.setText(opt[(flag * 4) + 1]);
        rb3.setText(opt[(flag * 4) + 2]);
        rb4.setText(opt[(flag * 4) + 3]);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String uansText = uans.getText().toString();
                if (uansText.equals(ans[flag])) {
                    Correct++;
                } else {
                    wrong++;
                }
                int len = question.length;
                flag++;
                if (flag < len) {
                    que.setText(question[flag]);
                    rb1.setText(opt[(flag * 4)]);
                    rb2.setText(opt[(flag * 4) + 1]);
                    rb3.setText(opt[(flag * 4) + 2]);
                    rb4.setText(opt[(flag * 4) + 3]);

                } else {
                  Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Result.class);
                  startActivity(in);
                }


            }
        });

        chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String uansText = uans.getText().toString();
                if (uansText.equals(ans[flag])) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your Ans Is Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your Ans Is Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: length function not contain "()" round brackets ?

Comment: String Array not contain round brackets but String contain round brackets.

Comment: i was trying to que.length(); that is length of textview instead of question.length my mistake

Comment: Hmm,finally you know your mistake.

Comment: @radhe12,if my ans is useful to you then can you please approve and upvote thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just remove = sign from if condition or replace your code with the following code... hope this help

```
if(flag<len)
        {
            que.setText(question[flag]);
            rb1.setText(opt[(flag*4)]);
            rb2.setText(opt[(flag*4)+1]);
            rb3.setText(opt[(flag*4)+2]);
            rb4.setText(opt[(flag*4)+3]);

        }
        else {

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Result.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
```

Comment: this will not work null pointer exception
and only two questions display not displaying last one

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity Component info{com.example.quizapp/com.example.quizapp.Result};java.lang.nullpointerException

Comment: there is problem with your Result class and please post whole logcat so can have better idea but first cross check your Result class..

Comment: public class Result extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
  tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  
  tv.setText("your marks is:" + Question.Correct);
 }
code of result class

Comment: may be there is problem with Question.Correct cross check this value

Comment: yup problem solve but only two question display instead of three
thnak you  problem in Result. class is solved